# Cassandra Clustering Single Node

Tags: cassandra, replication, cluster-computing

Well I have one node cluster and I have divided into two address 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2. Using Cassandra Client if I try to insert the data into 127.0.0.1. The data successfully gets add for 127.0.0.1 and I can view it also but If I try to connect to view from 127.0.0.2, I cannot see any update. There is no data. I think I was unable to explain it well last time.Here is what I did copied two cassandra into different folders with the name Cassandra 1 and Cassandra 2 on same node. Update the Cassandra.yaml accordingly.

1)

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
initial_token: 
data_file_directories: - /Cassandra/1/var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /Cassandra/1/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
saved_caches_directory: /Cassandra/1/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches 
- seeds: "127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2" 
listen_address: 127.0.0.1 
rpc_address: 127.0.0.1
```

2)

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster' 
initial_token: 
data_file_directories: - /Cassandra/2/var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /Cassandra/2/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
saved_caches_directory: /Cassandra/2/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
- seeds: "127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2" 
listen_address: 127.0.0.2 
rpc_address: 127.0.0.2
```

The others settings are the default setting and I have not modified anything. Then I create a keyspace and column family using:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options = [{replication_factor:2}];
```

I have not specified any partioner so defauly is Random I guess.

```
use demo; 

create column family order with comparator=UTF8Type and key_validation_class=UTF8Type and default_validation_class=UTF8Type and column_metadata=[{column_name: member, validation_class: UTF8Type},{column_name: user, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS},{column_name: instrument, validation_class: UTF8Type},{column_name: price, validation_class: DoubleType}, {column_name: quantity, validation_class: Int32Type},{column_name:datetime, validation_class: DateType}];
```

Now if I try to connect to 127.0.0.1 and insert the data, I belive that data should be inserted for both 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 but it's not the case.

```
Set orders[KEY][user] = 'ABC' list orders;
```

Is there anything wrong ? What should I do to make it workable.

Please give me a detail example if you have any. I think I am doing something wrong while creating keyspace, Column family and data insertion. If you have an example with two node insertion would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem after attempting to give different port numbers for the native transport. It must be the same port (9042 by default), otherwise the nodes do not find each other. The IP address must be different to prevent the port conflicts between the nodes.

Use `./nodetool status` to check if you have actually made a cluster and not simply a two isolated instances.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using both IP as seed, set it to single IP whichever is booted first.

what does "nodetool --host [127.0.0.1|127.0.0.2] ring", says. are you able to see both ip in custer.

Comment: Yes, I am using both IP as seed. I have changed the INFO level to DEBUG to make it sure that both communicate but I can only see one IP at a time.Both IP not communicating.

Comment: Yes, I am using both IP as seed and if I set to single IP as Seed then I get an exception when I run the 2nd Server.